Can I install a screw all the way through these threaded fork crown holes?
I've got a ~2006 Trek 520 and the fork crown area has a threaded hole on both the front and back as pictured. Note that this bike is set up with V-brakes and the hole is not used for a front brake. Both front and rear are M6x1.0 threaded.
Front of hole: 
Back of hole: 
The issue is that when I take a long full threaded M6 screw and install it from the front, it does not want to thread into the back hole. The screw can thread into the back hole, if I start it from the back. It's almost as if the front and rear threads are not "in sync" if that makes sense. Here is how it looks when I thread it in from the front.


You can see from the second photo that it makes its way to the back hole but won't go any further. In my younger days, I would have used more force but I am more cautious now and knowing that I'm not a frame expert, I am wondering if this isn't something I am supposed to be doing anyway. I don't want to damage the threads or frame.
Note that this frame was originally somewhat rusty when I got it and I  had it sand-blasted and powder coated. However, most of the small threads were not really cleaned up with the sand blasting process. So it's possible that there's simply some rust left over and a little more force, maybe some WD40, is all it would take. But I want to be sure.
So, should I just try to gently force it along or is it this way for a reason?
Background:
Why am I doing this? Good question. The bike doesn't have a threaded plate on the underside of the fork crown. The fenders that I am trying to install provided a "Daruma" bolt through which you are supposed to thread another bolt which is not provided with the fenders. The Daruma then attaches the fender and is held up by this bolt.
Thanks!
Note: the threads in that back hole look kind of bad in the pictures but they are actually fine in real life. It was hard to get a camera phone in there to take a good photo.

Your perception is correct the threads are not in sync. This occurs when the front is tapped from the front side and the rear is tapped from the rear side. Your options could include drill the rear threads out and use a bolt with a nut. Use a smaller bolt that will pass through both holes and use a nut. You could use a different type of fender or mount that is compatible with your fork.

They might actually be bushes (installed in separate operations) rather than being directly threaded into the metal. In any event, it might be possible to replace one with a Helicoil to keep the threads original, but IMO that would require a machine shop to be certain it was accurate.

Ah OK, good to know why they are not in sync and that makes sense. I think I will likely just use an L-bracked instead and attach it to only one of the holes. I don't like the idea of drilling threads out of my frame. And using a smaller M5 bolt seems like it would be wobbly and make clicking sounds and potentially damage the threads over years of bumpy roads, no?

@DanK I use an M5 bolt on my fork with a nylock nut to hold the mudguards on. Doesn't rattle around at all. Just make sure you do it up nice and tight. If you're worried, you could always wrap the bolt in electrical tape where it passes through the fork to stop any rattles.

Unless I'm misreading something, is not possible to use two bolts (one for each side of the steerer)? If not, I would turn to using an M5 bolt as mikes suggested. I don't think it's necessarily to destructively drill out some of the threads. You are correct in observing that it's unwise to exert more force--you're pretty much just gonna strip out whichever threaded section is weaker than the other. From a manufacturing perspective, it does make sense that the threads are not "clocked" together--it would require an abnormally long tool and be somewhat more difficult to hold in place, all for very little if any benefit.

I'd go with M5 too. But I'll offer one more suggestion

Thanks! I could use two bolts but I was hoping to use just one and hence this post. Using two bolts is also a bit more complex since I will need to shorten one of them so they meet exactly in the middle. Either that or have one (or both) sticking out. Or have a hole in the middle that the Daruma could get stuck in/fall through. If I use only a one bolt, the Daruma could fall off the end of that bolt. Unless, I size it to where it only goes up until the edge of the back hole. It could work. I don't really understand the M5 suggestion. It seems like it would just wobble and ruin the threads.

@DanK Ah, now I see how a Daruma bolt works (first time hearing about the things). Okay yeah you would want one long bolt. M5 would be fine if you tighten it up enough--it won't wobble if it's tight, and besides the Daruma should pull the bolt downwards and help keep things in place. I would hesitate to drill out the front threads as that would make it harder to potentially use a L-bracket (as another option) as Nathan suggests. Pretty sure every set of fenders I've installed used that setup, and it works well. Then you can just use a short bolt to attach the L to the front of the fork crown.

It's an interesting question because there aren't a ton of bikes that have this going on. Note there's likely some intentionality with having it threaded on both sides of the crown, but not caring about whether they're in sync. This setup lets you have one bolt in back for a fender and another in front for a rack, lights, and/or canti cable hanger. This gives you the functional upside that there's no interdependency causing by multiple angle-sensitive things being on the same bolt. If you need to play with the centering of your light at 3am on a dark roadside, you're not also inadvertently squirming the fender sideways and taking it off-center.
You could try to use a tap to force the threads into sync. This is basically a bad idea, though it might work. You're going to cut one thread form over the other one if you do that. That means both will have less material than they should. Even if it isn't holding a brake, there's no good reason to mess with this.
There's another piece to your question though, which is that darumas usually play really badly together with v-brakes. Darumas put the fender all the way up to the underside of the crown. V-brakes need it to be below the cable. There's nothing in the design of a fork that says those two heights are going to be the same, and what will usually happen if you put a daruma on a v-brake fork is it will be a mess of cable interference, which you may only discover after taking a bunch of trouble and/or drilling the fender, depending on which one it is. Make life easier on yourself and get a height-adjustable bracket that crimps over the fender or goes through the hole you were going to use for the daruma (VO and Honjo include this bracket for example, IIRC). Darumas are very good in specific installations where you're running the max tire size and there's no need to adjust the fender height up and down now or later, and where a sheet metal bracket might eat into clearance, but other than that they're flawed.

Great explanation of why they did it this way. I was curious.

Clearance is somewhat limited here but I will explore the L-bracket option since that seems the easiest. I don't think that having the fender all the way up to the fork crown would interfere with any cables on my bike but I will have to mock it up later today to be sure.

I sort of like this option since it doesn't require anything to be crimped: https://velo-orange.com/products/vo-single-hole-l-bracket

@DanK Yes that L-bracket is the more practical choice on a lot of bikes. It's just the world we're living in. A lot of touring/cross bikes in this vein have a bit too much "empty" space under the crown to use a daruma.

For mudguards, a smaller (M5) bolt would be fine.  However I'll offer details of one more option:
Choose which thread you want to keep, and drill out the other.
I'd keep the front thread for mounting lights, and mount my mudguard on the other end of the same long bolt using a nut - I'm more likely to want to get the mudguard off than the light.  If there are brakes (not in this case) their thread should always be kept.
As for what size to drill, 6.5mm (realistic) or 6.6mm (preferred normal fit) are best.  If you want a close fit 6.4mm is specified, but 1/4" should work.

Thanks, I still don't understand how an M5 wouldn't just rattle around and damage the threads over time. Are the sizes you mention your recommendations for the hole size to drill?

@DanK you'd do up an M5 tight, probably with a locking nut so it doesn't work loose.  You don't want it moving, but the threads aren't what would suffer first if it did (the accessories mounted using it are more likely to flex and break if not done up properly.
